# Unable to insert data in PostgreSQL 11.0 table

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I would like to insert values into postgresql 11.0 table. However, when I am trying to do that I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I am running following code:

```
#CREATE TABLE
try:
    connect_str = "dbname='xx' user='xx' host='xx' " "password='xx' port = xx"
    conn = psycopg2.connect(connect_str)
except:
        print("Unable to connect to the database") 

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl""")

try:
    cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl(
            entry_id CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
            name CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
            class CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
            ko_id CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,

            PRIMARY KEY (entry_id))
            """)
except:
        print("The table cannot be created!")
        
conn.commit()
conn.close()
cursor.close()
```

```
#INSERT DATA INTO TABLE
try:
    connect_str = "dbname='xx' user='xx' host='xx' " "password='xx' port = xx"
    conn = psycopg2.connect(connect_str)
except:
        print("Unable to connect to the database") 

cursor = conn.cursor()

with open ('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.match('^[A-Z]+',line) and line.startswith("ENTRY") or line.startswith("NAME") or line.startswith("CLASS") or line.startswith("KO_PATHWAY"):
            key, value = line.split(" ", 1)
            #print (key, value)
            if key == "ENTRY":
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tbl (entry_id) VALUES (%s)",('value'))
                
conn.commit()
conn.close()
cursor.close()
```

The key-value looks like this:

```
ENTRY       map00010                    Pathway

NAME        Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis

CLASS       Metabolism; Carbohydrate metabolism

KO_PATHWAY  ko00010

ENTRY       map00011                    Pathway

NAME        Glycolysis

CLASS       Metabolism; Carbohydrate

KO_PATHWAY  ko00011
```

The value map00010 Pathway and map00011 Pathway should be inserted in the table and create two rows.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Two things: 1) Don't quote `value`. 2) This `(value)` should be `(value,)`. Single element tuples need a trailing comma after the element per Python syntax.

Comment: I am getting this error: NotNullViolation: null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (      map00010                    Pathway
, null, null, null).

Comment: You have declared the columns to be `NOT NULL` so they all need a value on `INSERT`. Either supply a value or add a `DEFAULT` value to the column definition that will be supplied instead.